# vmware. error: file not found Ubuntu fails to boot after upgrading version

Tags: ubuntu, ubuntu-12.04, vmware, ubuntu-14.04

I Have upgraded my ubuntu 12 to 14.04 on vmware. After it is done, it seems that I get 4 messages displaying "error: file not found" and then it just hangs there.

Any suggestions for recovering?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I had the exact same problem.
Reinstalling grub just after the upgrade (don't reboot at the end of the upgrade) solved it:

```
grub-install /dev/sdX
update-grub
```

Comment: grub-install and update-grub are separate commands. Works great!